# Why Coroutine Method Work Only Once Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that I want to move by swipe, for example when the swipe is up the object should move forward smoothly from point A to point B, swipe right the object move smoothly to the right etc...

To do that, I've tried **Lerp**, **MoveTowards** and **SmoothDamp** but every time the object just disappear from point A and appear on point B instantly.

So I used coroutine to give a time to the movement, and as you can see in the code bellow, there's 4 coroutine methods, each one is for a direction. the problem I have is that when playing, the first movement work properly, but in the second swipe the object didn't reach the destination point, and the third one also and the object have some weird movements.

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

**Here's the Coroutine methods for movements:**

```
public IEnumerator MoveForward()
{
    Vector3 DestinationF = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + DistanceF); 
    while (Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, DestinationF) > 0)
    {
        float totalMovementTimeF = 0.3f;
        float currentMovementTimeF = 0f;
        currentMovementTimeF += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, DestinationF, currentMovementTimeF / totalMovementTimeF);
        yield return null;
    }
}
public IEnumerator MoveBackward()
{
    Vector3 DestinationB = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - DistanceB);
    while (Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, DestinationB) > 0)
    {
        float totalMovementTimeB = 0.3f;
        float currentMovementTimeB = 0f;
        currentMovementTimeB += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, DestinationB, currentMovementTimeB / totalMovementTimeB);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

> and there is still 2 coroutine methods MoveRight() and MoveLeft().

**And here's the code for the swipe directions:**

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //save began touch 2d point
        firstPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        //save ended touch 2d point
        secondPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

        //create vector from the two points
        currentSwipe = new Vector3(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);

        //normalize the 2d vector
        currentSwipe.Normalize();

        // swipe up
        if (currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MoveForward());
        }

        // swipe down
        if (currentSwipe.y < 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MoveBackward());
        }

        //swipe left
        if (currentSwipe.x < 0 && currentSwipe.y > -0.5f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MoveLeft());
        }

        //swipe right
        if (currentSwipe.x > 0 && currentSwipe.y > -0.5f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MoveRight());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it likely that the condition to keep the `while()` loop running has evaluated as false? For example, is `Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, DestinationB)` still true?

Comment: @reckface Sorry, I didn't understand the question!

Comment: Coroutines in C# use the yield return in your while loop to "pause" execution in that method. If the condition in your `while(something is true)yield return null;` is no longer true, then the enumeration will stop.

Comment: @reckface Yes, but why the first coroutine method work fine and the next ones didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you **never** reach the target.

Your lerping with factor

```c#
currentMovementTimeF / totalMovementTimeF
```

makes not much sense since you reset it every frame to

```c#
var currentMovementTimeF = Time.deltaTime;
```

which in the most cases will be `< 0.3f` (this would mean you have only about 3 frames per second) so it will always be

```c#
currentMovementTimeF < totalMovementTimeF
```

and therefore

```c#
currentMovementTimeF / totalMovementTimeF < 1
```

So you always start a new interpolation **between** the current position and the target. So the distance gets smaller and smaller but literally never reaches the final position actually (though it seems so).

Additionally you mixed `position` and `localPosition` there so if the `GameObject` is not on root level it gets even worse!

---

What you would want instead is probebly either using [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) with a certain `speed`. (position based)

```c#
// adjust these in the Inspector
public float speed;
public float MoveDistance;

public IEnumerator Move(Vector3 direction)
{
    var destinaton = transform.position + direction * MoveDistance; 

    while (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destinaton) > 0)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, MoveDistance, Time.deltaTime* speed);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

`MoveTowards` makes sure there is no overshooting.

or using Lerp (time based) like

```c#
// adjust these in the Inspector
public float totalMovementTime = 0.3f;
public float MoveDistance;

public IEnumerator Move(Vector3 direction)
{
    var originalPosition = transform.position;
    var destination = transform.position + direction * MoveDistance;

    // here you could make it even more accurate
    // by moving always with the same speed 
    // regardless how far the object is from the target
    //var moveDuration = totalMovementTime * Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destinaton);
    // and than replacing totalMovementTime with moveDuration 

    var currentDuration = 0.0f;
    while (currentDuration < totalMovementTime)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originalPosition, destination, currentDuration / totalMovementTime);

        currentDuration += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    // to be really sure set a fixed position in the end
    transform.position = destinaton;
}
```

---

Another issue is that you currently still could start two concurrent coroutines which leeds to strange behaviours. You rather should either interrupt the coroutines everytime you start a new one like

```c#
if (currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
{
    // stop all current routines
    stopAllCoroutines();
    StartCoroutine(MoveForward());
}
```

or add a flag to have only one routine running and ignore input in the meantime:

```c#
private bool isSwiping;

public IEnumerator MoveForward()
{
    if(isSwiping)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Already swiping -> ignored", this);
        yield break;
    }

    isSwiping = true;

    //...

    isSwiping = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank youuu, you really saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

Your first Coroutine works because:
    Vector3 DestinationF = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + DistanceF);

will result in a positive position, so, the distance will be greater than 0:

```
while (Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, DestinationF) > 0)
```

On the other hand, while subtracting the distanceB from the z value:

```
Vector3 DestinationB = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - DistanceB);
```

may result in a negative value, therefore:

```
while (Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, DestinationB) > 0)
```

will start as < 0, so the condition is never met. Check your condition. Do you want absolute values, or not equal to 0?

Comment: I tried replacing > with !=, but the same result happen, the coroutine method is executed, but the object didn't reach the destination, and after swiping few times it have a weird random movement.

Comment: @Taik your methods are assuming a 3D space (you're manipulating the z axis) I just want to clarify that's what you intend right?

Comment: Yes it's 3D, I want the values for Vector3.Distance to be different of 0.

Comment: `Vector3.Distance` allways returns a value `>= 0`! How should a distance be negative?

Comment: @derHugo Yes I agree with you. Do you know how can I solve the issue?